# How do we use 'grep' but not skipping test cases that we want them run all the time?

Tags: intern

For example we have test 1, test 2,..., test N, login Test, logout Test, what if we want to run login, test 1, logout at one time for debugging?

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to specify that some tests are always included when using `grep`, so the only way to do this currently is to use a grep expression that matches only the tests you want to run, like `grep="\\b(login|test 1|logout)\\b"`.